# How to fix "./src/index.js Module not found: Can't resolve 'loadash" in my react app?

Tags: reactjs

I am working with pagination in my react application which requires "_" element to be imported from Loadash file. Though I have installed load dash 4.17.11 and checked the node folder myself, I still get the error "./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'loadash' in '/Users/sivarajan/videolib/src'"

Comment: What way are you importing it? Can you show some code?

Comment: import _ from "loadash"; in the component file. I could see that the error is for index.js. I tried importing loadash there we well. The error is shown only after deploying my app.

Comment: *** import React from "react";
import _ from "loadash";

const pagination = props => {
  const pages = _.range(1, pagesCount + 1);

  return (
    <nav>
      <ul className="pagination">
        {pages.map(page => (
          <li className="page-item">
            <a className="page-link" onClick={() => props.onPageChange(page)}>
              {page}
            </a>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};
export default pagination;

Comment: You can edit your question and post the code there. Also, I left an answer. Can you try that?

Comment: Yes, you were right..I typed loadsh instead or lodash. I am editing my code now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `lodash` (no A) not `loadash`.

Comment: Yes, I checked it again to see my mistake there. editing it now. Thanks :-)

Comment: Cool, if it helps you can mark the answer as correct :)